# what options are there for dateFormat in as.xts() in R

Tags: r, date, xts, date-formatting

When transforming a matrix/dataframe etc into a xts object I often use the function `as.xts()`.
If my initial object has an index containing plain Dates like "2020-06-20", the output of `as.xts()` will have a timezone added like "2020-06-20 CEST".

I know there is an buildin option `dateFormat`, but I don't what values I can pass into that. Is there a list of possible inputs somewhere? I can't find any in the documentation the only one I know is "POSIXct"

```
new_xts_object <- as.xts(my_matrix, dateFormat="POSIXct")
```

So what else `dateFormat`'s are there? And is there one just like `as.Date()`, a plain date format?

Comment: Are you trying to control the time zone?

Comment: Yes I was manually removing them in an extra step, but wanted to solve this directly within as.xts(). So dateFormat="Date" does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find such a list in `help("index.xts")`:

> The specified value for `tclass<-` must be a character string containing
> one of the following: `Date`, `POSIXct`, `chron`, `yearmon`, `yearqtr` or
> `timeDate`.

Trying it:

```
library(xts)
library(timeSeries)

x <- timeSeries(1:10, 1:10)
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "POSIXct")
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "POSIXlt")
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "Date")

library(chron)
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "chron")

library(timeDate)
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "yearmon")
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "yearqtr")
as.xts(x, dateFormat = "timeDate")
```

Comment: Perfect, simply using "Date" does exactly what I was hoping for, namely getting rid of the timezones without removing them in an extra step. Thank you!